# How to use debounce on async function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, debouncing

How can I use `debounce` on an `async` function? I have a method within my `vue`-app which reveives data from an API which calls the API continuosly which I want to avoid.

Here is my method:

```
methods: {
    async getAlbums () {
     const response = await AlbumService.fetchAlbums()
     this.albums = response.data.albums
    } 
}
```

I've installed `lodash` previously so how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Lodash's [`debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce) function takes in a function , time to wait and returns a function.

So do it like this:

```
methods: {
  getAlbums: _.debounce(async function() {
    const response = await AlbumService.fetchAlbums();
    this.albums = response.data.albums;
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be returning values properly when used with await

Comment: Only works when the lodash debounce leading option is set to true.

Comment: @user1843640 Sorry to hijack an old comment but is there a reason for it only working with `leading : true`? For me this causes unwanted behaviour, like if the user types 'search' in a search field then it will do the search only on 's'

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal, have you found any away to return the value with async.

Comment: @ChrisA because `leading: true` call the method immediately so the promise that we are expecting is available. unfortunately the `lodash.debounce` is not working properly with `leading: true`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52505376/leading-true-in-debounce-not-performing-as-expected