# Leading=true in debounce not performing as expected

Tags: react-native, lodash, debouncing

Using lodash's `debounce()`, I'm waiting 10 seconds before setting a search term in my app's state. But I want to set `searching` in my app's state before I debounce:

```
onChangeText(text) {
    setSearching(true);
    setSearchTerm(text);
}
render(){
    return(
        <TextInput style={s.input}
            onChangeText={_.debounce(this.onChangeText, 10000, {'leading':true} )}
        />
    )
}
```

[From the docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce), this should run on the leading edge of the timeout, and not until the events stop for the allotted wait time. **The actual behavior is as if there is not debounce at all, the events run each time as they are called without a 10 second buffer. Any ideas?** Removing the `{'leading':true}` does do the debounce appropriately, but I need to set state in my app before the 10 seconds.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Seems like a bug in lodash?

Comment: @Operator I'm not sure what I did to resolve this. I know `'leading'` is not in quotation marks in my current projects and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

See if this approach would help:

```
debouncedSetSearchTerm = _.debounce(text => setSearchTerm(text), 10000)

onChangeText(text) {
    setSearching(true);
    debouncedSetSearchTerm(text);
}
render() {
    return(
        <TextInput style={s.input} onChangeText={onChangeText} />
    )
}
```

You would first `setSearching` and then call the `debouncedFn` which would then deal with the `searchTerm` after the 10000 delay.

Comment: `TypeError: Expected a function`

Comment: I tested this locally so I am pretty sure it works. The approach is the more important thing here anyway ... just play with the contents of the `_.debounce()` but this is they way to get your state set and then debounce.

Comment: I'm trying this solution, it does set the state first, but performs an ajax call for every letter typed after the delay

Answer (score 0):

You can specify leading true in your user case.

```
debounce(func, [wait=0], [options={ leading: true}])
```

Please read doc from link https://lodash.com/docs#debounce

Comment: `onChangeText={ _.debounce(this.onChangeText, 1200, [options={leading:true,trailing:true}]) }` is the same behavior as default.

Comment: It looks like the correct syntax is `onChangeText={ _.debounce(this.onChangeText, 1200, {'leading':true,'trailing':false} ) }` but this gives me a behavior similar to no debounce at all, which is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever will stumble upon this question again, [the docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) say:

> Note: If leading and trailing options are true, func is invoked on the trailing edge of the timeout only if the debounced function is invoked more than once during the wait timeout.

Therefore you might need to use `{ leading: true, trailing: false }` to get what you want, because trailing is true by default.

Comment: Link to the docs?

Comment: @MuhammadSiddiqui just use the link from the question. The note is the second paragraph. But I also added the link to my answer now.