# Jest test not passing for debounce function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, debouncing

I have this function

```
import _ from 'underscore';
const configMap = {};
export function someFunctionName(someValue, dispatch, reduxAction) {
  if (!configMap[someValue]) {
    configMap[someValue] = _.debounce(
      (someValue) => dispatch(reduxAction(someValue)),
      1000,
    );
  }
  return configMap[someValue];
}
```

with jest tests:

```
const dispatchMock = jest.fn();
const reduxAction = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({});

jest.useFakeTimers();
describe('someFunctionName', () => {
  it('should dispatch reduxAction', async () => {
    someFunctionName('value', dispatchMock, reduxAction);
    jest.runAllTimers();
    expect(reduxAction).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Test keeps failing and i'm not sure why. I initially thought it could be the debounce method needs a mock, but that doesn't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Lodash's `debounce` function is asynchronous which means the return statement of `someFunctionName` is going to execute before `debounce` comes back with a value. Additionally, the function inside `debounce` is not going to run until the provided wait time of 1000ms has elapsed.

You'll need to add async logic to wait for the result of `debounce` within `someFunctionName` before returning. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58055085/lodash-debounce-async-await) may provide further help on how to achieve this.